# How to pass a value retrieved from HttpContext to BackgroundJob.Enqueue

Tags: hangfire

I have this code in my controller:

```
var user = HttpContext == null ? null 
                               : HttpContext.Items["ApplicationUser"] as ApplicationUser;
int organisationid = user == null ? 0
                                  : user.OrganisationID;
BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => Merge(organisationid));
```

So the background job calls the Merge method in my controller:

```
public void Merge(int organisationid)
{
    _Uow.MergeSHQSCostsTable(organisationid);
}
```

But I would like the call in the merge method to use the `organisationid` retrieved from the request and available at the time the call to `Enqueue` is made. How do I do that? Currently my code always passes the value zero because the `HttpContext` is null when the background job is run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to encapsulate the call to `BackgroundJob.Enqueue` in a separate method so that Hangfire can serialise the parameter:

```
public SHQSController(IUnitOfWork uow) : base(uow)
{
   //CurrentOrganisationID is retrieved from HttpContext
   EnqueueMerge(CurrentOrganisationID);
}

private void EnqueueMerge(int organisationid)
{
    BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => Merge(organisationid));
}
```